# How to make a nonblocking wait handle?

Tags: c#, wpf, autoresetevent, waithandle

Essentially, what I'm doing is creating a web server to handle an API call, and then when it's done continue the method execution, so essentially:

```
new WebServer(myAutoResetEvent);
myAutoResetEvent.WaitOne();
```

However, this blocks the thread until then. Is there any way to make this async? Is it fine just to wrap it in a `await Task.Run()` call, i.e. `await Task.Run(() => myAutoResetEvent.WaitOne())`?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you give more details? Is this code on the server side or the client side?

Comment: @YacoubMassad This is a wholly client side app. Basically I'm making a reddit oauth2 request which then redirects to 127.0.0.1:someport, which I then intercept to get the query strings so that I can ask for a reddit API token, but I need to wait for that to happen before I can carry on the execution.

Comment: Which line is blocking the thread? I imagine you are calling `myAutoResetEvent.WaitOne()` for this thread to be blocked. If the constructor `new WebServer(myAutoResetEvent)` is blocking the thread, why do you need the `myAutoResetEvent.WaitOne()`?

Comment: @Vikhram The webserver is waiting for its first request, which I will then take the query params from. When this first request happens, myAutoResetEvent's `Set` method will be called.

Comment: Can you add sample code showing which line is blocking. I understand the premise, but the devil is in the implementation details, right :) ?!?!

Comment: @Vikhram The WaitOne line is blocking, waiting for the ARE to be `Set()`

Comment: OK. I assumed that is your intention. `myAutoResetEvent.WaitOne()` tells the system to block the current thread till the `myAutoResetEvent.Set()`  is called. `myAutoResetEvent.WaitOne()` serves no other purpose, or does it? What I mean to say is, if `myAutoResetEvent.WaitOne()` is blocking and you don't want it to block, you should simply delete that line. Am I missing something here?

Comment: @Vikhram the asker wants the remainder of the method to continue after `Set()` is called but without blocking the thread.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Normally, the `WebServer` ctor should not do anything interesting. There should be a `Task WebServer.RunAsync` function that runs the server. You can then use the resulting task to synchronize and coordinate.

If you don't want that you can use a `TaskCompletionSource<object>` as a one-shot async-ready event.

I believe the `ThreadPool` class has a way to efficiently wait for a `WaitHandle` to be set but that's a worse solution.

Comment: It's for a very lightweight application so I'm just gonna use this: https://codehosting.net/blog/BlogEngine/post/Simple-C-Web-Server.aspx - there's no RunAsync method. A `TaskCompletionSource` seems like a good idea, though! Let me try that out :D

Comment: Yep, the TaskCompletionSource works :D Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4):

You should not block `ThreadPool` threads, this is a quick way to lead to `ThreadPool` starvation, instead there is a provided method to asynchronously wait for `WaitHandle` instances, this is called `ThreadPool.RegisterWaitForSingleObject`.

By using `ThreadPool.RegisterWaitForSingleObject` a callback is registered to be invoked when the `WaitHandle` is available, unfortunately this is not async/await compatible out of the box, a full implementation which makes this async/await compatible is as follows:

```
public static class WaitHandleExtensions
{
    public static Task WaitOneAsync(this WaitHandle waitHandle, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {    
        return WaitOneAsync(waitHandle, Timeout.Infinite, cancellationToken);
    }

    public static async Task<bool> WaitOneAsync(this WaitHandle waitHandle, int timeout, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {    
        // A Mutex can't use RegisterWaitForSingleObject as a Mutex requires the wait and release to be on the same thread
        // but RegisterWaitForSingleObject acquires the Mutex on a ThreadPool thread.
        if (waitHandle is Mutex)
            throw new ArgumentException(StringResources.MutexMayNotBeUsedWithWaitOneAsyncAsThreadIdentityIsEnforced, nameof(waitHandle));

        cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();

        var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();
        var rwh = ThreadPool.RegisterWaitForSingleObject(waitHandle, OnWaitOrTimerCallback, tcs, timeout, true);

        var cancellationCallback = BuildCancellationCallback(rwh, tcs);

        using (cancellationToken.Register(cancellationCallback))
        {
            try
            {
                return await tcs.Task.ConfigureAwait(false);
            }
            finally
            {
                rwh.Unregister(null);
            }
        }
    }

    private static Action BuildCancellationCallback(RegisteredWaitHandle rwh, TaskCompletionSource<bool> tcs)
    {    
        return () =>
        {
            if (rwh.Unregister(null))
            {
                tcs.SetCanceled();
            }
        };
    }

    private static void OnWaitOrTimerCallback(object state, bool timedOut)
    {    
        var taskCompletionSource = (TaskCompletionSource<bool>)state;

        taskCompletionSource.SetResult(!timedOut);
    }
}
```

The only limitation is that this cannot be used with a `Mutex`.

This can be used like so:

```
await myAutoResetEvent.WaitOneAsync(cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

Comment: Not bad. If the TCS does not work for him this would be a very good solution.

Comment: It seems it is better to use simply AsyncAutoResetEvent variations, which use Task underneath and as the name suggests are fully async/awaitable: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pfxteam/2012/02/11/building-async-coordination-primitives-part-2-asyncautoresetevent/

Comment: Static typing, cleaner code, and my personal preference actually -- no `IDisposable`. No big deals, just "it seems it is better..." :-) On related note -- you introduced tiny bugs in the code, you should use `TrySetXXX`, not `SetXXX`.

Comment: The blog post you linked has no cancellation support, no timeout support and requires you to reimplement each of the coordination types which is a lot more work. If you've seen a bug happen, some source demonstrating would be great.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach to consider would be to use `HttpSelfHostServer` (System.Web.Http.SelfHost.dll) and leaving all of the threading details to its implementation.

```
var config = new HttpSelfHostConfiguration("http://localhost:9999");
var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<Uri>();

using (var server = new HttpSelfHostServer(config, new MessageHandler(tcs)))
{
    await server.OpenAsync();

    await tcs.Task;

    await server.CloseAsync();
}

return tcs.Task.Result;

class MessageHandler : HttpMessageHandler
{
    private readonly TaskCompletionSource<Uri> _task;

    public MessageHandler(TaskCompletionSource<Uri> task)
    {
        _task = task;
    }

    protected override Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        _task.SetResult(request.RequestUri);
        return Task.FromResult(new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK));
    }
}
```

Comment: This might be a better webserver implementation for me to use. Thanks for the advice!

Comment: @It'sNotALie You're welcome! Please upvote answers if you find them useful.